# How to aligment nodes with highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to alignment nodes, But I cant see any options how to do it,
Currently my code is

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'networkgraph',
    plotBorderWidth: 1
},
title: {
    text: 'Trans-Siberian Railway'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Barnes-Hut approximation'
},
plotOptions: {
    networkgraph: {
        layoutAlgorithm: {
            enableSimulation: false,
            linkLength: 100,
            integration: 'verlet',
            approximation: 'barnes-hut',
            gravitationalConstant: 4,
                // Elastic like forces:
            attractiveForce: function (d, k) {
             return (k - d) / d; 
            },
         /*    repulsiveForce: function (d, k) {
                return Math.min((k * k) / (d), 100);
            } */

        }
    }
},
series: [{
    marker: {
        radius: 3,
        lineWidth: 1
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        linkFormatter: function () {
            return '';
        }
    },
    nodes: [

       {
        id: 'test',
        marker: {
            radius: 10
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'Moscow',
        marker: {
            radius: 10
        }
    }, {
        id: 'Beijing',
        marker: {
            radius: 10
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'Brussels',
        marker: {
            radius: 10
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'Bangkok',
        marker: {
            radius: 10
        }
    }],
    data: [
        { from: 'Bangkok', to: 'Beijing', color: 'blue' },
        { from: 'Moscow', to: 'Beijing', color: 'blue' },
         { from: 'test', to: 'Moscow', color: 'blue' },
       { from: 'Beijing', to: 'Brussels', color: 'blue' },




    ]
}]
```

});

the result of code is:

[image: w]
and its still not alignment the wanted results is

[image]

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wj0pudb1/?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel but it still not like I wanted basically all should be like straight lines  like example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set fixed positions in the networkgraph chart by using the **initialPositions** callback. To work it well you need also to set maxIterations to some small value, like 1.

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ft7e6bjm/1/)

```
initialPositions: function() {
    var chart = this.series[0].chart,
      width = chart.plotWidth,
      height = chart.plotHeight;
      
    this.nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
        if(i === 0){
        node.plotX = 600;
        node.plotY = 100;
      }
      
      if(i === 1) {
        node.plotX = 350;
        node.plotY = 100;
      }
      
      if(i === 2){
        node.plotX = 200;
        node.plotY = 0;
      }
      
      if(i === 3) {
        node.plotX = 0;
        node.plotY = 0;
      }
      
      if(i === 4) {
        node.plotX = 200;
        node.plotY = 200;
      }
    });
  }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.layoutAlgorithm.maxIterations

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.layoutAlgorithm.initialPositions

---

If you want to have those points not draggable, maybe an easier solution will be to render regular line chart?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/06Lkgwbz/

Comment: wow that cool demos the issue is the what if you have more dynamic way, like if you  will have test2 node  that connected to Brussels ,  how to manage the calculation ? Also what if you will not have Brussels then the graph isnt aligment to one line...

Comment: @VitalyMenchikovsky To render those positions dynamically you will need to implement your own algorithm. I tried to implement something like this but without success - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2fpvLszg/ . I have a problem with implementing the bottom lines. Maybe you will be able to achieve it.